# How can I see the original sas macro code?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm trying to debug code used in a SAS program, but the program uses macros from a permanent library.  I can't find the code that created the macros and I don't have access to the person who created the original library.  I know that `option mprint;` will show me the lines of code that the macro executes, but I would like to see all of the code that a macro uses so that I can more easily debug it.  In other words, I would like to have all the information that would be available to me if I had the original program that generated the macros.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two possible ways you could be executing a SAS macro from a permanent library.  Either you are using an autocall macro, or a stored compiled macro.

An autocall macro would mean you do have access to the source, because it's simply a .sas file with the name of the macro as the name of the file.  You can %include the file and see the full text, assuming you know which directory it is in (you can have many autocall libraries).  So if your `SASAUTOS` directory is `c:\sas\macros\`, and you are calling `%mymacro()`, then you could execute

```
%include "c:\sas\macros\mymacro.sas";
```

which would include the pre-compiled text, and as long as you have the `source2` option enabled, it will print to your log.

A stored compiled macro can be viewed only if it was compiled with the `SOURCE` option.  If it was not, then you *cannot* retrieve the macro source code (without having access to the program that created the SCM).

If it was compiled with `SOURCE`, then you can use the `%COPY` macro statement to copy the source code from the SCM to your log:

```
%copy mymacro / SOURCE;
```

More details are available in the SAS documentation, or from the excellent paper [Ways to Store Macro Source Codes and How to Retrieve Them](http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2005/AD07_05.PDF).

Comment: Regrettably, I have a stored compiled macro and the `SOURCE` option was not used, but at least I won't continue wasting time trying to get the original code out.

Answer (score 0):

If your macro was sourced from a directory, then `options MAUTOLOCDISPLAY;` will logprint the location from which the macro code was compiled into WORK.

See [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/62978/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p04o0tz0t7g88in1mqlh27hj7wgn.htm)